# How to implement SOAP communication for .net application

Tags: c#, php, web-services, soap, wsdl

I have to implement SOAP based communication between a .NET application and a local courier service. They have provided good documentation of their SOAP service with php samples and wsdl schema at http://www.rapido.bg/soap_help/, but I cannot find my way in implementing it for .NET with C#.

I looked at similar problems online and first tried to add the wsdl as Service reference which didn't create the necessary classes, then tried to add it as Web Reference, which generated the classes and methods, but could't generate some of the parameter types as expected. For example the login parameter was generated as string, whereas in the wsdl it is defined as xsd:struct and in the php sample its created and passed as an anonymous class with two fields.

I tried to implement the communication using web requests and building the SOAP messages manually following some other approaches, but still couldn't get it right.

It will be great if someone can get a simple app working or just let me know how to do it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try using [WseWsdl2.exe](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms827743.aspx), it will generate C# or VB.Net classes for you that can be used to communicate with the SOAP service of your choice.